# How to create a multi-volume RAR archive and create par2 recovery files with a batch file?

Tags: winrar

I have a batch that create par2 recovery files for *WinRAR* archives.

But unfortunately the batch created only for archive xxx.part1.rar the par2 files ...

That is the line I use for compressing the folders:

```
if "!FolderName:_UNPACK_=!" == "%%~nxF" (
    "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" m -ep1 -hp[password] -pxxx -mt5 -m1 -v50M -r "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\%_RndAlphaNum%" "%%~F"
)
```

That is the line I use for par2 the RAR archive files:

```
"C:\Program Files\xxx\phpar2.exe" c -r5 -b3000 "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xxx\*.rar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce any problem.

Running `phpar2.exe` without any parameter results in printing the help into command prompt window:

```
phpar2 version 1.3, Copyright (C) 2003 Peter Brian Clements.

phpar2 comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.

This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your
option) any later version. See COPYING for details.


Usage:

  phpar2 c(reate) [options] <par2 file> [files] : Create PAR2 files
  phpar2 v(erify) [options] <par2 file> [files] : Verify files using PAR2 file
  phpar2 r(epair) [options] <par2 file> [files] : Repair files using PAR2 files

Options:

  -b<n>  : Set the Block-Count
  -s<n>  : Set the Block-Size (Don't use both -b and -s)
  -r<n>  : Level of Redundancy (%%)
  -c<n>  : Recovery block count (Don't use both -r and -c)
  -f<n>  : First Recovery-Block-Number
  -u     : Uniform recovery file sizes
  -l     : Limit size of recovery files (Don't use both -u and -l)
  -n<n>  : Number of recovery files (Don't use both -n and -l)
  -m<n>  : Memory (in MB) to use
  -v [-v]: Be more verbose
  -q [-q]: Be more quiet (-q -q gives silence)
  --     : Treat all remaining CommandLine as filenames

If you wish to create par2 files for a single source file, you may leave
out the name of the par2 file from the command line.
```

It is advisable although not necessary to specify a file name for the par2 file when recovery data should be created for multiple files at once.

For example with current directory being `C:\Temp` and directory `C:\Temp\Test` containing

```
Test.part01.rar
Test.part02.rar
Test.part03.rar
Test.part04.rar
Test.part05.rar
Test.part06.rar
Test.part07.rar
Test.part08.rar
```

with each file having 4 MB except the last one and running now

```
phpar2.exe c -r5 -b3000 "C:\Temp\Test\*.rar"
```

the output printed to console window by `phpar2.exe` is

```
Block size: 9784
Source file count: 7
Source block count: 3003
Redundancy: 5%
Recovery block count: 150
Recovery file count: 8

Opening: Test.part02.rar
Opening: Test.part03.rar
Opening: Test.part04.rar
Opening: Test.part05.rar
Opening: Test.part06.rar
Opening: Test.part07.rar
Opening: Test.part08.rar
Computing Reed Solomon matrix.
Constructing: done.
Wrote 1467600 bytes to disk
Writing recovery packets
Writing verification packets
Done
```

and the directory `C:\Temp\Test` contains additionally

```
Test.part01.rar.par2
Test.part01.rar.vol000+01.par2
Test.part01.rar.vol001+02.par2
Test.part01.rar.vol003+04.par2
Test.part01.rar.vol007+08.par2
Test.part01.rar.vol015+16.par2
Test.part01.rar.vol031+32.par2
Test.part01.rar.vol063+64.par2
Test.part01.rar.vol127+23.par2
```

With using the command line

```
phpar2.exe c -r5 -b3000 TestRecovery.par2 "C:\Temp\Test\*.rar"
```

the files created by `phpar2.exe` in current directory `C:\Temp` are

```
TestRecovery.par2
TestRecovery.vol000+01.par2
TestRecovery.vol001+02.par2
TestRecovery.vol003+04.par2
TestRecovery.vol007+08.par2
TestRecovery.vol015+16.par2
TestRecovery.vol031+32.par2
TestRecovery.vol063+64.par2
TestRecovery.vol127+23.par2
```

That is the correct result.

---

But `WinRAR` supports adding recovery data directly to each RAR file or to separate recovery volume files. This can be done by either using WinRAR with command `rr` (adding recovery data) or `rv` (creating recovery volumes) or using on archive creation directly option `-rr` or `-rv`.

For your batch example the command line for creating 1 or more separate recovery volumes with 5% recovery data for all parts of the multi-volume archive is:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" m -cfg- -ep1 -hpPassword -inul -mt5 -m1 -r -rv5p -v50M "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\xxx\%_RndAlphaNum%" "%%~F"
```

Note: `Rar.exe` calculates automatically how many recovery volumes with 50 millions of bytes maximum file size (50 MB would require a lower case written, i.e. `-v50m`) are required for all parts of the multi-volume archive.

For more details about recovery data read text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* which is the manual for the console version `Rar.exe`.

The commands and switches for GUI version `WinRAR.exe` for usage from command line (batch file) is included in help of *WinRAR*, see after opening **Help - Help topics** on help tab **Contents** the items under **Command line mode**.

Whether `Rar.exe` nor `phpar2.exe` create one recovery file for each part of the multi-volume archive. The created recovery file(s) contain the recovery data for all parts of the multi-volume archive.